# Is it possible to specify the range of the Y-Axis

Tags: java, javafx, orson-charts

I have my Area chart created in the code below

```
chart = Chart3DFactory.createAreaChart("", // Main title
                "", // Sub title
                dataset, null, "Date", // X-Axis legend
                "Time (seconds)"); // Y-Axis legend


        chart.setChartBoxColor(new Color(255, 255, 255, 127));
        chart.setLegendAnchor(LegendAnchor.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        CategoryPlot3D plot = (CategoryPlot3D) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setGridlinePaintForValues(Color.BLACK);
        chartViewer = new Chart3DViewer(chart);
        borderPane.setCenter(chartViewer);
```

[image]

My values in the graph are above 200 and I would like to specify the Axis to start at 200. I haven't found much documentation on the [official website](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/) or [Github.](https://github.com/jfree/orson-charts-fx/commits?author=jfree)
Does anyone know if it's possible ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never looked at this library before, so I'm sorry if this answer is incorrect.

I see that your `plot` is of the type [`CategoryPlot3D`](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/javadoc/com/orsoncharts/plot/CategoryPlot3D.html). This class has the method [`getValueAxis()`](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/javadoc/com/orsoncharts/plot/CategoryPlot3D.html#getValueAxis--) which returns a [`ValueAxis3D`](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/javadoc/com/orsoncharts/axis/ValueAxis3D.html) object. The `ValueAxis3D` interface extends from the [`Axis3D`](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/javadoc/com/orsoncharts/axis/Axis3D.html) interface. And this last interface has these two methods:

- [`setRange(Range)`](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/javadoc/com/orsoncharts/axis/Axis3D.html#setRange-com.orsoncharts.Range-)
- [`setRange(double, double)`](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/javadoc/com/orsoncharts/axis/Axis3D.html#setRange-double-double-)

Where I believe the the latter method is just a convenience method so you do not have to create a [`Range`](http://www.object-refinery.com/orsoncharts/javadoc/com/orsoncharts/Range.html) object.

I hope this is what you were asking for?

Comment: Yes, that did what I was looking for thanks ! Here is the code I ended up using : ValueAxis3D valueAxis3D = plot.getValueAxis();
  valueAxis3D.setRange(200, 500);